# iPhone contact style app (how to configure labels)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am trying to make a contact app style image + labels (screenshot). I can't figure out how to configure the labels next to the image to look exactly like in the contact app.

Anyone has figured out the settings? (font, shadow color, offset etc.)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helvetica-Bold, 18pt, black text, white shadow, shadow offset - `CGSize(0,1)`. You are welcome.